# A simple tab implementation with <ul><li> but how to set tab background-image?

Tags: html, css

I implemented a simple **tab navigation** by using `<ul><li><a>` , the problem is that there are several "**layers**" on each tab still needed. what I mean is, In my current implementation I have:

- -tab text which is `<a>text</a>`
- -on each tab I have a tab icon image, which I put on `<li>` as background-image of `<li>`,

**But I still need:**

- -tab **seperator image** (A vertical bar image) which I intend to put on `<a>`,and position it on the left side `background-position: left` , it is working but this implementation is not in my code which I showed below on *jsfiddle* site because I did not find a suitable image on internet
- -tab background image which occupy the whole tab, I have no idea where I should put this image?

Please check & run my implementation [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pq7LC/38/), in the css code, I used `background-color` instead of `background-image` just to express what I want to achieve, but I need to use `background-image` as the tab background.

**What I tried:**

- I tried to put the **tab background image** on `<li>` but it will hide the
  **icon image** which has already on `<li>`,
- I tried to put the **tab background image** on `<a>` but it will also hide the **tab seperator image** when mouse hover

How to get rid of this **layer probelm** on tab implementation then? (Please do not suggest me to use less image, since it is one requirement of this app to use those images.)

(By the way, all images I mentioned have mouse "hover" counterpart)

Comment: do you have a design file(image) of your final results?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the HTML, you can use pseudo-elements:

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pq7LC/39/**

```
li:before{
    content: "";
    background: pink;
    width: 20px;
    height: 61px;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}
li:first-child:before{ /* Don't add image border before first li */
    content:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with css, no need of images.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pq7LC/40/

Hope it helped you :)